# Sort multidimensional array based on the value of a particular index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$externalData=array((array("a","b",3,"d"),array("f","g",1,"h),...))
```

I want to sort the arrays inside $externalData based on the numeric index (in this case at index 2, so the second array should come first once $externalData is sorted).

Is this possible? How? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Comment: can you share expected result as is not quite clear what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the case above: array("f","g",1,"h),array("a","b",3,"d") because at index 2 there's 1 and at index 0 there's 3

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: indeed it is, sorry, I haven't noticed that question

Comment: No worries, @IanBell - Actually I had an idea for an answer but when I Googled to fact-check something it was the SO question that came up first in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $externalData = array(array("a","b",3,"d"), array("f","g",1,"h"));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($externalData);
    usort($externalData, function ($a, $b) {
         return $a[2] - $b[2];
    });
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($externalData);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Chech here : https://eval.in/540934

Comment: This is indeed how I would do it.